Как вывести переменную по частям
Например у меня есть переменная a= 123456789  Как вывести ее с дефисами следующим образом "12-345-67-89"

Способов очень и очень много, но нужна конкретная логика. Где и когда ставить дефисы. Между каждой третьей цифрой или может после каждой конкретной, или сначала после двух, потом трёх и потом снова двух. В общем, нужна более конкретная логика. А вариантов даже базовыми способами великое множество.

И на всякий случай напомню, что это форум для помощи в решении ошибок, а не сервис по решению задач за других. Вы не предоставили никакой попытки решить проблему самостоятельно.

Форматируйте удобно:
def format(fmt, n):
    it = iter(str(n))
    return ''.join(next(it) if c == '#' else c for c in fmt)


print(format('##-###-##-##', 123456789))


$ python format.py
12-345-67-89


Добавлена проверка, что все цифры выведены. Программа остановится если цифр слишком много или слишком мало:
def format(fmt, n):
    it = iter(str(n))
    s = ''.join(next(it) if c == '#' else c for c in fmt)
    for _ in it:
        assert False
    return s


Тут нехорошие вещи получаются, если в форматной строке много решёток.

@rotabor, процедура ломается. Формат специально сделан жестким, чтобы не печатать чепуху, если формат не соответствует данным. Всегда можно добавить ранний выход если данные кончились, или вывод пустоты на место отсутствующих данных или метасимвол для всех оставшихся цифр. Требуется больше информации, а пока жесткий формат. Я бы его ещё ломал, если цифры остались а формат кончился.

Как-то так?
b = str(123456789)
print(b[0:2]+'-'+b[2:5]+'-'+b[5:7]+'-'+b[7:9])

Или
a=[2,3,2,2]
b=str(123456789)

i=0
def sslice(n):
  global i
  j=i
  i+=n
  return b[j:i]

print("-".join(map(sslice,a)))


Спасибо, попробую

global это плохо, нет гарантии, что где-то в коде не будет переменной с таким же именем и вы её не испортите.

@CrazyElf это концепция, демонстратор, а не финальное решение. Тут и b в функции используется.

@CrazyElf А не подскажете, почему в функции sslice переменная b не требует global, а i - требует?

@rotabor Потому что переменные, которые изменяются в функции, считаются по умолчанию локальными, а которые только читаются - глобальными.

def ins_minus(s:str, pos:list)->str:
    ls=list(s)
    cpos=0
    for i in pos:
        cpos+=i
        if cpos < len(ls):
            ls.insert(cpos,'-')
        cpos+=1
    return ''.join(ls)

a = '123456789'
t = [2,3,2,2]
print(ins_minus(a,t))

a = '1234567890'
t = [5]
print(ins_minus(a,t))

a = '1234567890'
t = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
print(ins_minus(a,t))

a = '1234567890'
t = [3,3,2,2]
print(ins_minus(a,t))


12-345-67-89
12345-67890
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0
123-456-78-90

